# The java printing code is working,send to printer but not print anything(java in python)

Tags: java, python, ios, multithreading, printing

i have made various research on this,plus,i'm using python,which i actually implement java in python script.Somehow,the record is send to the printer(i even got the message about this)but it does not print.can anyone help me on this,i'm stuck on this.thanks.

This is the code,i got no error for this.

```
import system
import javax.print
import java.io
from java.lang import Thread

filestream = java.io.BufferedInputStream(java.io.FileInputStream("C:/GEEKS.txt"))

psInformat = javax.print.DocFlavor.INPUT_STREAM.AUTOSENSE

myDoc = javax.print.SimpleDoc(filestream,psInformat,None)

aset = javax.print.attribute.HashPrintRequestAttributeSet()
aset.add(javax.print.attribute.standard.Copies(2))

services = javax.print.PrintServiceLookup.lookupDefaultPrintService()

job = services.createPrintJob()

job.print(myDoc, None)

Thread.sleep(20000)

filestream.close()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are trying to send a .docx file to the printer; the print service almost certainly doesn't know how to render and print a .docx file.  Try sending a plain text file.

Comment: i have try it using test.txt..but seems like no luck sir.